# Does the Wiener Filter Achieve the Cramer Rao Lower Bound (CRLB)?

Tags: estimation, parameter-estimation, linear-prediction, bayesian-estimation, wiener-filter

I have been told (Wikipedia agrees) that the Wiener filter is optimal when signal and (additive) noise are WSS. Optimal in the sense that it minimizes the mean-square error.

The Cramér–Rao bound is the lower bound on the variance of an unbiased estimator of a deterministic parameter.

Does that mean that the Wiener filter operating at the Cramér–Rao bound?

Comment: Here's few page paper related to Wiener & Cramér–Rao bounds - https://tinyurl.com/y4njfzmv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While [@Gideon Genadi Kogan](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/users/34391/gideon-genadi-kogan) answer touches some of the issues the main thing is not whether we can define all signal as a set of parameters or not.

The [Cramer Rao Lower Bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%E2%80%93Rao_bound) is a lower bound for a parametric model.
The [Wiener Filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_filter) is a Bayesian Method with its loss function defined as the [MMSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_mean_square_error).

So basically they don't have the same modeling of the data.
For Cramer Rao the parameter is fixed but unknown, for the Wiener Filter the data is stochastic.

Answer (score 2):

Cramér–Rao is a lower bound for variance of parameter estimation. Wiener filter is used for the estimation of a signal rather than the variance of parameters.

In some formulations, the Cramér–Rao can be used for estimation of the lower bound of multiple parameters. Nevertheless, treating a signal as a set of parameters seems like a little bit of stretching the definition.

So main differences are:

1. The number of the parameters - multiple VS signal length.
2. Estimation of variance VS estimation of values.